# 503 Google API Error, possible limit on requests? Should we setup a Retry?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

We are getting the below error message **intermittently** for our customers pushing videos to YouTube, using api version 3.  Is there a limit to how many videos can be uploaded at a time?  If so, what is that limit?

If we reach the limit, can we set up a retry until we are able to upload again?

**Error message:**

```
Upload attempt failed. 

Additional debug info:
<HttpError 503 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&part=snippet%2Cstatus returned "Backend Error">

Item : Using Groups to Manage Resources for V5.X    tmp_vid_path: /mnt/tmp/vid-distro-232-youtube-raw.mp4
```

**We are using:**

```
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
```

**Here is the meat of the upload video call:**

```
youtube_service = get_yt_service(credential)
result = youtube_service.videos().insert(part="snippet,status",
                                            body=body,
                                            media_body=media_body)
```

Please note that **get_yt_service()** is simply a wrapper to the build function, imported from **apiclient.discovery**

Comment: From what I remember, the limit is hourly. Once you get a 503, you have to wait an hour (or sign up for the paid API).

Comment: @Blender Where is that bit of info stated? I don't see anything about hourly limits in the official docs... (I'm hit by the same problem as the OP, and trying to diagnose it/work around it)

Comment: @AndresF.: I don't know if they changed it recently, but here's the page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/faq#operation_limits